# How to add alternating blank lines when saving csv file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, save

I have a dataframe and I want to save it to a csv file. This operation is quite simple because I just need to use the following command:

```
df.to_csv(namefile, sep='', index=False)
```

The output is a csv file where each line contains the content of the a row of the dataframe. The output is this:

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,1,2,3
```

However, what I would like to do is to have a blank line every other row so that the output looks like this:

```
A,B,C,D

1,2,3,4

5,6,7,8

9,1,2,3
```

Basically I need to add the **CR** and **LF** symbol between every other line.
Can you suggest me a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter `line_terminator='\n\n'`:

> **line_terminator** : string, default '\n'
>
> The newline character or character sequence to use in the output file

Demo:

```
df.to_csv(namefile, line_terminator='\n\n')
```